# print div class elements

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have a div class:-

```
<div class="hidden">
This is it.
       <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" 
        Height="23px" style="margin-top: 0px" Width="69px" text="Print" OnClientClick="PrintElem('#hidden'); return false;"/>
</div>
```

inside this div class, a list of elements that are dynamically populated.
I am trying to use a print button inside this div class to print all elements.

```
function PrintElem(elem) {
            Popup($(elem).html());
        }

        function Popup(data) {
            var mywindow = window.open('', '#hidden', 'height=400,width=600');
            mywindow.document.write('<html><head><title>Pharmacy List</title>');
            /*optional stylesheet*/ //mywindow.document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css" type="text/css" />');
            mywindow.document.write('</head><body >');
            mywindow.document.write(data);
            mywindow.document.write('</body></html>');

            mywindow.print();
            mywindow.close();

           return true;
        }
```

**This works great, except the page that is printed out is blank and titled 'undefined'.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`OnClientClick="PrintElem('#hidden')` you're trying to print an element with an id of hidden NOT a class of hidden.

Answer (score 0):

In your code above `#hidden` is for `id="hidden"` whereas `.hidden` would need to be used for `class="hidden"`